# Do K8S Service Load Balancers need to wait for a Pod to be completely healthy?

Tags: kubernetes

Recently our deploy failed because a sidecar that provides non-critical functionality in our pod failed to pull it's image. The pod was in a crashloop, but the important services in that pod were healthy and ready to go.

A service load balancer is stood up to expose those services to the web. The LB was listed as active and healthy, but connections were failing to the services therein. After disabling the failed sidecar container, connections were working again.

--

In this scenario, it wasn't directly a critical error that the sidecar failed to pull, but it resulted in a critical failure of refusing connections to a service that was otherwise ready. Is there a way to configure a Kubernetes service LB start even if the pod is having issues?

Comment: `kubectl explain service.spec.publishNotReadyAddresses`? But it all still depends on how your LB is actually implemented.

Comment: If the endpoint/metric you have set up for the health check is dependent on the sidecar then yes. in theory your health mettric could be a static page with the word "true" which would in no way tell that your application is healthy. In my opinion, the health setup should be thought about carefully. It it easy  to make it over-inclusive